# Move Windows System, Page File, and Hibernation file to SSD while keeping other programs on same drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I was going to propose this as an answer to how to move hyberfile.sys to another volume but this forum appears to be broken.

I see a lot of articles that start to explain how to move the windows system to another drive, but they are all off on some key details.

I want to boot off my D: drive and keep all my program files and such on the C: Drive...  either that or rename the SSD to C: and remount the existing HDD as D and update all the shortcuts to point to D.

I know it may be possible to do a fresh install on the SSD, but then the question is how do I restore my settings and user folder to point to the D drive. Where everything was carefully installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 wants to run in C for some reason, and any install will get the installed drive to get the letter C. The only option is to reinstall Windows to the SSD. Once that is done, you can move the program files to D, but the easiest trick to keep things working is by replacing it with a junction. `mklink /j "c:\Program Files" "d:\Proram Files"` and the same for the (x86) version. Now, keep installing to the C drive and understand that it will automatically end up on the D drive.

For this to work, you will have to perform the operation outside of windows though as files will be in use. If you are skilled with the command prompt, the easiest way is to use the windows 10 usb stick you made to install windows 10, boot from it and on the first setup screen, press shift-f10 to open a command prompt.

Alternatively, boot into recovery (hold shift while pressing reboot) and search for the command prompt there.

Comment: So, I could use the mklink for program files, user directory and all that too?   how about the registry?  i have a lot of programs configured (silly steps to get solidworks pdm to work were painful, so many versions of solid works installed because opening it in a newer version means it can't go back, all kinds of other stuff installed too)   I almost just want to clean re-install and put the other drive in if i want to use rare software..

Comment: I also asked microsoft if they could support putting the Hibernation file on a different drive...  should be no technical reason why not.

Comment: You're missing the point here. When you create a directory junction, you still have Program Files on your C drive, except, whenever you access it, you are tunneled to the D drive. So it no longer consumes space on your C drive, but for the rest of the system, it still thinks its on C. So you don't need to alter the registry, and just keep using it on the C drive without worrying that it takes up space.

Comment: You can do this trick with almost all folders. As for the users folder, I would recommend not doing it on C:\Users, but on the folders inside your profile. So c:\users\Username\desktop = yes, c:\users\usersname = no. Otherwise it will break loading your profile, and you'll get a temporary profile on each boot.

Comment: Appreciate the correction in spelling. As this wasn't answered elsewhere, I don't get why it is negative one...